# Save image using JQuery and WebMethod

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to save image to a folder using JQuery and WebMethod in vb.net. But I got **parameter is not valid** exception while I am  trying to convert the stream to image.

HTML

```
<div>
        <input id="imgInput" type="file"  name="file"/>
        <img id="imagePreview" src="" alt="Item Image" width="96" height="80"/>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="save image"  onclick="saveimage();"/>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#imgInput").change(function () {

                readURL(this);

            });

        });
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {

                    $('#imagePreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        function saveimage() {
            var imageInByte = encodeURIComponent($('#imagePreview').attr('src'));

            var fname = $("#imgInput").val();
            var splitval = fname.split('.');
            var fnames = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000) + 1);
            var submitval = JSON.stringify({ data: imageInByte, fname: fnames, ext: splitval[1] });
          //  alert(submitval);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                data: submitval,
                url: "test.aspx/saveimage",
                success: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

web service

```
<WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Sub saveimage(ByVal data As String, ByVal fname As String, ByVal ext As String)
        Dim bytearray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(data)
        Dim base64str = Convert.ToBase64String(bytearray)
        Dim imgarr As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(base64str)
        Dim streams As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(imgarr, 0, imgarr.Length)
        streams.Write(imgarr, 0, imgarr.Length)
        If Not streams Is Stream.Null Then
            Dim retimage As Image
            Try
                retimage = Image.FromStream(streams, True, True)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

Please Help me to solve this issue and save image to a folder.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Please rename your question title. It's not helpful. Do you get an error or an exception? Please be precise. What is the exception message?

Comment: @ThomasW. please go through the question i edited it.

Comment: Let's see: you are converting the image to JSON format, then post it to the saveimage() method. There you convert it to UTF32, then to Base64, write that into a MemoryStream and try reading this as an image? Do me a favor and attach a Debugger, look at the variables in each of those steps and you'll find the problem.

Comment: @ThomasW. then please suggest me a good way to do this..thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're encoding the image, filename and extension parameters as a JSON object on before sending, but not decoding from JSON on the other end.

I believe your `saveimage` function is expecting three parameters but only getting one, a JSON string

You either need to send all three parameters separately, or change your `saveImage` function to accept one string param and decode it from JSON into an object.